MongoDB server fails to start due to unhandled exception 0xC000001D unless data folder is cleared
I have the free version of mongodb on Windows 10.
The service and the database work for two days. Then the service fails to start, and I need to clear the database directory for the service to work.
Since then the same cycle keeps happening, the service (either by running mongod.exe or by the automatic start of the service on system startup) works fine for the first 2-3 startups after the last "cleanup" and then every subsequent attempt fails until the next "cleanup".
The service crashes after successfully performing recovery and replaying log files.
"Writing minidump diagnostic file","attr":{"dumpName":"C:\\mongodb\\bin\\mongod.2024-12-13T16-12-07.mdmp"}}
"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"

Full log from running mongod.exe (fail):
[{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.892+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.893+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.894+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set at least one of the related parameters","attr":{"relatedParameters":["tcpFastOpenServer","tcpFastOpenClient","tcpFastOpenQueueSize"]}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.895+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":25},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":25},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":25},"isInternalClient":true}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.898+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"TENANT_M", "id":7091600, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry"}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.898+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":9752,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-JABS99V"}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.898+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.898+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"8.0.3","gitVersion":"89d97f2744a2b9851ddfb51bdf22f687562d9b06","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc-gperf","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.898+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19045)"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.899+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.902+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.902+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=3528M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],prefetch=(available=true,default=false),"}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:05.981+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106325,"ts_usec":981027,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 4 through 5"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.095+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":94776,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 5 through 5"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.248+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":247678,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Main recovery loop: starting at 4/384 to 5/256"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.471+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":471543,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 4 through 5"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.608+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":607456,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Recovering log 5 through 5"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.701+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":701403,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery log replay has successfully finished and ran for 721 milliseconds"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.702+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":701403,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.702+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":702399,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.705+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":705107,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery rollback to stable has successfully finished and ran for 2 milliseconds"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.720+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTCHKPT",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":720085,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"WT_SESSION.checkpoint","category":"WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS","category_id":7,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"saving checkpoint snapshot min: 1, snapshot max: 1 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0) base write gen: 33"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.790+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":790326,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery checkpoint has successfully finished and ran for 84 milliseconds"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.791+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WTRECOV",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1734106326,"ts_usec":790627,"thread":"9752:140732063570064","session_name":"txn-recover","category":"WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS","category_id":34,"verbose_level":"DEBUG_1","verbose_level_id":1,"msg":"recovery was completed successfully and took 810ms, including 721ms for the log replay, 2ms for the rollback to stable, and 84ms for the checkpoint."}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.808+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":906}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.808+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.822+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23134,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unhandled exception","attr":{"exceptionString":"0xC000001D","addressString":"0x00007FF6BAACCBAF"}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:06.822+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23136,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** stack trace for unhandled exception:"}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.458+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"7FF6BAACCBAF","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":1493,"s":"snappy::SnappyDecompressor::DecompressAllTags<snappy::SnappyArrayWriter>","s+":"16F"},{"a":"7FF6BAACE088","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":2082,"s":"snappy::RawUncompress","s+":"F8"},{"a":"7FF6BAACE3DD","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy-c.cc","line":58,"s":"snappy_uncompress","s+":"4D"},{"a":"7FF6BAE25C94","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/ext/compressors/snappy/snappy_compress.c","line":179,"s":"snappy_decompression","s+":"54"},{"a":"7FF6BAEE8387","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/block_cache/block_io.c","line":189,"s":"__wt_blkcache_read","s+":"717"},{"a":"7FF6BAEB8C3B","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/btree/bt_handle.c","line":833,"s":"__btree_preload","s+":"3AB"},{"a":"7FF6BAEB956B","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/btree/bt_handle.c","line":149,"s":"__wt_btree_open","s+":"36B"},{"a":"7FF6BAE21EEB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/conn/conn_dhandle.c","line":561,"s":"__wt_conn_dhandle_open","s+":"39B"},{"a":"7FF6BAE8FC67","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_dhandle.c","line":953,"s":"__wt_session_get_dhandle","s+":"B7"},{"a":"7FF6BAE8FFD5","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_dhandle.c","line":946,"s":"__wt_session_get_dhandle","s+":"425"},{"a":"7FF6BAE8F571","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_dhandle.c","line":477,"s":"__wt_session_get_btree_ckpt","s+":"F1"},{"a":"7FF6BAE41251","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/cursor/cur_file.c","line":1215,"s":"__wt_curfile_open","s+":"3E1"},{"a":"7FF6BADC94E8","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":699,"s":"__session_open_cursor_int","s+":"C8"},{"a":"7FF6BADD5109","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":739,"s":"__wt_open_cursor","s+":"89"},{"a":"7FF6BAE63119","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/cursor/cur_table.c","line":1102,"s":"__wt_curtable_open","s+":"E9"},{"a":"7FF6BADC94AC","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":606,"s":"__session_open_cursor_int","s+":"8C"},{"a":"7FF6BADC909D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":802,"s":"__session_open_cursor","s+":"3FD"},{"a":"7FF6B95B3DA1","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp","line":98,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_openCursor","s+":"41"},{"a":"7FF6B95B4720","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp","line":146,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerSession::getNewCursor","s+":"20"},{"a":"7FF6B95CA56E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp","line":1832,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerRecordStore::getLargestKey","s+":"9E"},{"a":"7FF6B9581672","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_impl.cpp","line":334,"s":"mongo::CollectionImpl::SharedState::SharedState","s+":"2A2"},{"a":"7FF6B9580DF0","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_impl.cpp","line":355,"s":"mongo::CollectionImpl::CollectionImpl","s+":"170"},{"a":"7FF6B958D5F5","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_impl.cpp","line":374,"s":"mongo::CollectionImpl::FactoryImpl::make","s+":"125"},{"a":"7FF6B96051A7","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_impl.cpp","line":479,"s":"mongo::StorageEngineImpl::_initCollection","s+":"257"},{"a":"7FF6B9608A04","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_impl.cpp","line":446,"s":"mongo::StorageEngineImpl::loadCatalog","s+":"1D54"},{"a":"7FF6B9601D0F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_impl.cpp","line":167,"s":"mongo::StorageEngineImpl::StorageEngineImpl","s+":"1CF"},{"a":"7FF6B95A007F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_init.cpp","line":162,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::WiredTigerFactory::create","s+":"80F"},{"a":"7FF6B9693557","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp","line":188,"s":"mongo::initializeStorageEngine","s+":"7F7"},{"a":"7FF6B88B9A47","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":597,"s":"`mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen'::`2'::<lambda_2>::operator()","s+":"77"},{"a":"7FF6B88BC02A","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":591,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen","s+":"B3A"},{"a":"7FF6B88BF41E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":1221,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::initAndListen","s+":"1E"},{"a":"7FF6B88C27AF","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":2224,"s":"mongo::mongod_main","s+":"7BF"},{"a":"7FF6B88A69BA","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod.cpp","line":41,"s":"wmain","s+":"2A"},{"a":"7FF6BB0057DC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/a01/_work/43/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/startup/exe_common.inl","line":288,"s":"__scrt_common_main_seh","s+":"10C"},{"a":"7FFEBCA87374","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}]}},"tags":[]}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.472+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAACCBAF","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":1493,"s":"snappy::SnappyDecompressor::DecompressAllTags<snappy::SnappyArrayWriter>","s+":"16F"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.473+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAACE088","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy.cc","line":2082,"s":"snappy::RawUncompress","s+":"F8"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.474+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAACE3DD","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/snappy/dist/snappy-c.cc","line":58,"s":"snappy_uncompress","s+":"4D"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.475+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE25C94","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/ext/compressors/snappy/snappy_compress.c","line":179,"s":"snappy_decompression","s+":"54"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.476+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAEE8387","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/block_cache/block_io.c","line":189,"s":"__wt_blkcache_read","s+":"717"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.476+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAEB8C3B","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/btree/bt_handle.c","line":833,"s":"__btree_preload","s+":"3AB"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.477+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAEB956B","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/btree/bt_handle.c","line":149,"s":"__wt_btree_open","s+":"36B"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.478+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE21EEB","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/conn/conn_dhandle.c","line":561,"s":"__wt_conn_dhandle_open","s+":"39B"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.479+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE8FC67","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_dhandle.c","line":953,"s":"__wt_session_get_dhandle","s+":"B7"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.480+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE8FFD5","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_dhandle.c","line":946,"s":"__wt_session_get_dhandle","s+":"425"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.481+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE8F571","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_dhandle.c","line":477,"s":"__wt_session_get_btree_ckpt","s+":"F1"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.494+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE41251","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/cursor/cur_file.c","line":1215,"s":"__wt_curfile_open","s+":"3E1"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.495+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BADC94E8","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":699,"s":"__session_open_cursor_int","s+":"C8"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.498+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BADD5109","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":739,"s":"__wt_open_cursor","s+":"89"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.499+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BAE63119","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/cursor/cur_table.c","line":1102,"s":"__wt_curtable_open","s+":"E9"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.499+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BADC94AC","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":606,"s":"__session_open_cursor_int","s+":"8C"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.500+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BADC909D","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/third_party/wiredtiger/src/session/session_api.c","line":802,"s":"__session_open_cursor","s+":"3FD"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.501+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B95B3DA1","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp","line":98,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_openCursor","s+":"41"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.502+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B95B4720","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_session_cache.cpp","line":146,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerSession::getNewCursor","s+":"20"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.503+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B95CA56E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_record_store.cpp","line":1832,"s":"mongo::WiredTigerRecordStore::getLargestKey","s+":"9E"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.507+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B9581672","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_impl.cpp","line":334,"s":"mongo::CollectionImpl::SharedState::SharedState","s+":"2A2"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.508+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B9580DF0","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_impl.cpp","line":355,"s":"mongo::CollectionImpl::CollectionImpl","s+":"170"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.509+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B958D5F5","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/catalog/collection_impl.cpp","line":374,"s":"mongo::CollectionImpl::FactoryImpl::make","s+":"125"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.510+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B96051A7","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_impl.cpp","line":479,"s":"mongo::StorageEngineImpl::_initCollection","s+":"257"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.511+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B9608A04","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_impl.cpp","line":446,"s":"mongo::StorageEngineImpl::loadCatalog","s+":"1D54"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.512+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B9601D0F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_impl.cpp","line":167,"s":"mongo::StorageEngineImpl::StorageEngineImpl","s+":"1CF"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.512+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B95A007F","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_init.cpp","line":162,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::WiredTigerFactory::create","s+":"80F"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.513+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B9693557","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_init.cpp","line":188,"s":"mongo::initializeStorageEngine","s+":"7F7"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.526+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B88B9A47","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":597,"s":"`mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen'::`2'::<lambda_2>::operator()","s+":"77"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.528+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B88BC02A","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":591,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::_initAndListen","s+":"B3A"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.529+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B88BF41E","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":1221,"s":"mongo::`anonymous namespace'::initAndListen","s+":"1E"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.530+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B88C27AF","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod_main.cpp","line":2224,"s":"mongo::mongod_main","s+":"7BF"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.531+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6B88A69BA","module":"mongod.exe","file":".../src/mongo/db/mongod.cpp","line":41,"s":"wmain","s+":"2A"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.532+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FF6BB0057DC","module":"mongod.exe","file":"d:/a01/_work/43/s/src/vctools/crt/vcstartup/src/startup/exe_common.inl","line":288,"s":"__scrt_common_main_seh","s+":"10C"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.533+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FFEBCA87374","module":"KERNEL32.DLL","s":"BaseThreadInitThunk","s+":"14"}}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.534+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23132,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Writing minidump diagnostic file","attr":{"dumpName":"C:\\mongodb\\bin\\mongod.2024-12-13T16-12-07.mdmp"}}
,{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-13T18:12:07.669+02:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23137,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"*** immediate exit due to unhandled exception"}
]

Build Info:
{
    "version": "8.0.3",
    "gitVersion": "89d97f2744a2b9851ddfb51bdf22f687562d9b06",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc-gperf",
    "environment": {
        "distmod": "windows",
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

CPU details: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz   3.10 GHz
The program files are in C:\mongodb.
I've tried using both C:\mongodb\data and C:\data\db as the data database path.
All users have full access to both database paths.
I've tried to uninstalling and reinstalling.
The database directory size is around 200MB before both failed and succesful attempts and the main hard drive volume has more than 100 unused GB.
I've tried running the app as an administrator.
Tried running .\mongod.exe --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zstd --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zstd and .\mongod.exe --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib but I still get the same error from dist/snappy.cc:1493.
Any help would be appreciated.

My guess would be file corruption. You aren't going to get far with only a Windows minidump. Try enabling the Mongo log verbosity: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.setLogLevel/

Exception 0xC000001D is illegal instruction. The Core i3 2100 was released in 2011, which should be supported by MongoDB, but is right at the cutoff (Sandy Bridge or higher). https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/administration/production-notes/#platform-support-notes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandy_Bridge

@GregAskew If it was a cpu issue, then shouldn't it always fail if the folder isn't empty or at least be less consistent? In this case it's works&empty, works&full, works&full, fails&full at which it's going to continue failing until I clear the contents.
